# For Loop Quitting Prematurely

Tags: iphone, objective-c, for-loop

Here's my loop

```
-(void)analyzeDataWithSearchTerm:(NSString *)searchTerm {

    [searchResults removeAllObjects];

    NSLog(@"number of items = %i", [itemIDRows count]);

    for (int i = 0; i < [itemIDRows count]; i++) {

        bool foundResult = FALSE;
        if ([[[itemIDRows objectAtIndex:i] lowercaseString] rangeOfString:[searchTerm lowercaseString]].location != NSNotFound) {
            NSLog(@"ID matches %@", [itemIDRows objectAtIndex:i]);
            foundResult = TRUE;
        }
        if ([[[itemNameRows objectAtIndex:i] lowercaseString] rangeOfString:[searchTerm lowercaseString]].location != NSNotFound) {
            NSLog(@"name Matches %@", [itemNameRows objectAtIndex:i]);
            foundResult = TRUE;
        }
        if ([[[barcodeRows objectAtIndex:i] lowercaseString] rangeOfString:[searchTerm lowercaseString]].location != NSNotFound) {
            NSLog(@"barcode Matches %@", [barcodeRows objectAtIndex:i]);
            foundResult = TRUE;
        }
        if ([aliasRows objectAtIndex:i] != [NSNull null]) {
            if ([[[aliasRows objectAtIndex:i] lowercaseString] rangeOfString:[searchTerm lowercaseString]].location != NSNotFound) {
                NSLog(@"alias Matches %@", [aliasRows objectAtIndex:i]);
                foundResult = TRUE;
            }
        }

        if (foundResult) {
            NSNumber *result = [NSNumber numberWithInt:i];
            NSLog(@"found result");
            [searchResults addObject:result];

        } else {
            NSLog(@"no result was found this time");
        }
    }

    if (isScanning) {
    //do something different
    }
}
```

The problem seems to occur if I have set "isScanning" to true (it's a bool) and run the method "analyzeDataWithSearchTerm" a second time.

Basically this loop checks if the item is already in a purchase order. If not the item is offered to be added. Next time the item is scanned the loop runs and goes through and should detect the item as being in the purchase order. I've setup break points but the second time the loop runs (only 2 items in the order) it finds one result, gets to the line `foundResult = TRUE`, doesn't set the bool to true, and the whole method just stops. It never even makes it to

`if (foundResult) { }`

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: Does the app error out and quit on you or does it keep running afterwards?

Comment: It keeps running just fine... it's just this method quits without actually finishing.

Comment: Which "foundResult = TRUE" is this happening on?  What happens inside of your ifScanning block?

Comment: the first one. itemID...

Comment: Interesting I just tried it where barcode would be true and it worked just fine... Curious... Then I added an item where itemID would be true. It detected barcode just fine but when it tried to detect itemID the loop quit prematurely.

Comment: Still, all other ifs will also be evaluated. Are you sure there does not occur an exception in (for example) the second if where you do something with itemNameRows? Is that array filled?

Comment: I think I figured out that I was forgetting to add objects to the barcodeRows MutableArray. After I did that it seemed to work. But why it doesn't throw an error is beyond me... I'm still not 100% sure that's the answer though. I got to fix another bug related to adding barcodes to be able to continue debugging.

Comment: Next time, you might want to be clear on what is actually going on before posting a question—since you stated in the question that setting isScanning to TRUE was what triggered the problem. :)

Comment: You're right... that was misleading. It was all related to the array missing a value.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem seems to occur if I have set "isScanning" to true (it's a
>   bool) and run the method "analyzeDataWithSearchTerm" a second time.

It would be helpful if you could confirm that this *is* when the problem occurs, and not just that it *seems* to be when it occurs. Presuming that is the case, the piece of code we most need to see is whatever is inside this:

```
if (isScanning) {
//do something different
}
```

The most logical conclusion is that something in the "do something different" is changing the conditions that would otherwise be examined in your loop, such as perhaps removing objects from itemIDRows (which I presume is an NSArray or NSMutableArray) or causing that NSArray/NSMutableArray object to be released.

Your use of `!= NSNotFound` seems like a strange test to me and is likely the cause of your problems. You could meet this criteria if there was another error other than NSNotFound—but could for example then stall on `[itemIDRows objectAtIndex:i]`. If you change your logic to matching the two strings, rather than *failing to not match*, I suspect your error will either disappear or the resulting problem elsewhere will more clearly highlight the problem.

Comment: No it was definatley because one of my arrays was missing an object. The method would simply quit after a result was found. it never would reach if (isScanning) so no it's wrong.